# Find a $1$-form $\alpha$ on $\Bbb R^3$ such that the kernel of $\alpha$ is orthogonal to $X$ with respect to the standard inner product on $\Bbb R^3$.

Tags: differential-geometry

Let $X$ be a non-vanishing vector field on $\Bbb R^3$, written in coordinates as
$$X=f \partial/\partial x + g\partial/\partial y +h\partial/\partial z$$ for smooth functions $f,g$ and $h$. Find a $1$-form $\alpha$ on $\Bbb R^3$ such that the kernel of $\alpha$ is orthogonal to $X$ with respect to the standard inner product on $\Bbb R^3$.

---

So let $\alpha_p = a(p)dx+b(p)dy + c(p)dz$ be a $1$-form on $\Bbb R^3$. We want $\alpha$ to satisfy that for any $v \in \ker(\alpha)$ the inner product $\langle X,v\rangle = 0$.

Suppose that $v = u \partial/\partial x + w\partial/\partial y +k\partial/\partial z$, then $$\langle X,v\rangle = uf+wg+kh = 0.$$

How can I get some condition for the coefficients of $\alpha$ from this?

Comment: Hint: the map $v \mapsto \langle X,v \rangle$ defines a $1$-form on $\Bbb R^3$...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just convert $X$ to a $1$-form $\alpha$ using the standard inner product, so that $\alpha(Y) = \langle X,Y\rangle$ immediately gives you the equivalence you need: $\alpha = f\,{\rm d}x+g\,{\rm d}y +h\,{\rm d}z$. This is really a linear algebra problem. On an Euclidean vector space $(V,\langle\cdot,\cdot\rangle)$, given $v\in V\smallsetminus \{0\}$, find $f\in V^*$ such that $\ker f$ is orthogonal to $v$; just take $f = \langle v,\cdot\rangle$ (or any nonzero multiple of it).